# How to deal with retained data after Activity comes to foreground when using more than one Activity?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, android-lifecycle

At the moment I'm a little bit confused about the lifecycle management in Android. There are at least 4 possibilities to resume retained data after an Activity comes back to the foreground:

- **Android handling:** If there is enough memory, Android stores and resumes the important data (checked radio buttons, text of EditText,-... and so on) after Activity restart, the user has the same state as before as the Activity went into background.
- **onPause, onResume:** Overriding onPause and save the important data to a database or text file and resume it when onResume is executed next time.
- **onSavedInstance(Bundle), onRestoreInstance(Bundle):** I can save the data as key-value-pair into bundles and restore them after onRestoreInstance is executed.
- **onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), getLastNonConfigurationInstance():** I handle all my storage issues in one big object and read getLastNonConfigurationInstance() out when onCreate is executed.

Although it is confusing which approach is best, I guess it relies on development experience to know when to use which possibility. If you have some good examples for each I would be glad, but this is not my question. I wonder how to deal with all that when I have different Activities and one Activity will be killed by Android when it pauses in background:

In my case I have a MainActivity and a MessageActivity. The MessageActivity consists of a ViewSwitcher which consists of two states. State one is a radio button choice list. State two is an EditText with two buttons (send and abort). When I monkey test each state, hit the Android home button, and restart the application, the right Activity with the right state and the old data comes into foreground, when I leave the handling to Android. So that works.
But what happens when Android destroys the MessageActivity in background: 
If I use the Android way, the data is lost and I guess MainActivity (instead of MessageActivity->state(1 or 2)) will start next time after I relaunch the application (is that correct?). So when I'd like to keep the data of MessageActivity, I have to use one of the other three possibilities.
How to do that neatly, when the application entry point (so the MainActivity) differs from the last active Activity. The problem is that I have to resume a special Activity with a special state of ViewSwitcher. I could start MessageActivity out of MainActivity with startActivity(Intent) in onStart() or onResume() method (because MainActivity is probably the entry point) but then I run into a lot of logical problems in Lifecycle management. Due to this fact I don't think that this is the right way to do that.

But, what's the right and best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess MainActivity (instead of MessageActivity->state(1 or 2)) will start next time after I relaunch the application (is that correct?)

No, I don't believe this is correct, depending on what your code does in onCreate(). It certainly doesn't *need* to be correct if you go about things the right way. A simple way to test this is to rotate your screen, which recreates the running activities, unless you have overridden the default configuration change behaviour.

I recommend reading this section in the android docs carefully:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState

In particular:

> even if you do nothing and do not implement onSaveInstanceState(), some of the activity state is restored by the Activity class's default implementation of onSaveInstanceState(). Specifically, the default implementation calls onSaveInstanceState() for every View in the layout, which allows each view to provide information about itself that should be saved. Almost every widget in the Android framework implements this method as appropriate, such that any visible changes to the UI are automatically saved and restored when your activity is recreated. For example, the EditText widget saves any text entered by the user and the CheckBox widget saves whether it's checked or not. The only work required by you is to provide a unique ID (with the android:id attribute) for each widget you want to save its state. If a widget does not have an ID, then it cannot save its state.

What this means is, that so long as you don't force any UI state in any `onCreate()` calls, your activity stack and UI state will be restored.

Personally, my preferred approach is to keep as little state as possible in member variables of my activities, saving and restoring it with `onSave/RestoreInstanceState()`, and relying on the default implementations to save the rest of the UI state (text box contents, etc). Data that should persist between sessions I commit straight to my DB or preferences as soon as it's changed (e.g. in the on-click handler). This means I don't need to worry about the activity lifecycle for that. As much as possible, my UI just presents a view of the data in my DB (using CursorAdapter etc.).

**Edit:**

Regarding restoration of the whole activity stack:

> When the user leaves a task by pressing the HOME key, ... The system retains the state of every activity in the task. If the user later resumes the task by selecting the launcher icon that began the task, the task comes to the foreground and resumes the activity at the top of the stack.

(See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't explain the following. When I have 4 Activities: Main, B, C, D. D is on top. I hit HOME and D goes to background. After a while, D will be destroyed because Android runs out of memory. It's unclear to me in which Activity onRestoreInstanceState is to implement and why this allegedly works that especially Activity D will be resumed. hovanessyan's solution is clear to me, but according to this article I wouldn't have known how to deal with onRestoreInstanceState when using many Activities. Honestly I don't see the part that the whole Activity stack will be resumed.

Comment: Potentially, you would implement onSave/RestoreInstanceState() in *all* activities. In each, you deal with only the state pertaining to that activity. That's it. Android will call any or all of them when necessary.

Of course, you only need to save & restore if the activity has state of it's own that must be preserved (i.e. member variables that cannot be trivially reinitialised on a restart).

Answer (score 2):

It's not my attempt for a best answer, but it's too long to get in the comments section.

First I will suggest not to rely on the "Android way" - this will result in inconsistent application behavior depending on the free memory of the device - bad practice.

My suggestion is to save your state-dependent data in key-value pairs in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), every time you  go into `onPause()` in your `MessageActivity`. Store a flag in `SharedPreferences`, which indicates which was the Activity that was last opened (if you only have two Activities you can easily go 0/1 or true/false flags). 
When you re-launch your application, it's normal to start the Activity marked in your AndroidManifest.xml as "entry point". So naturally you'll check the flag in `onResume()` in your `MainActivity` and start the other Activity if needed. In `MessageActivity's onResume()` check the values in `SharedPreferences` and fill in what's necessary...
If your application is "resumed" to the *last Activity in the ActivityStack* this will call `onResume()` in the *last Activity in the ActivityStack*.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have handled an issue like this in the past, is to have a service running in the background, which handles the flow of information from different activities via either Intents and listeners (preferable, since they are the most easily decoupled solution), or if you are extremely careful, and the only viable solution for some reason is to store the data through direct property access or method calls, you can use static properties/methods on the service class as well.  However, I would strongly recommend using the Intent/listener method as it is generally more flexible, thread safe, and decoupled.  Additionally, it is wise to make sure that not much is happening at any point in time (in other words, **only** use this service for Intent handling) when it's not needed, otherwise the Service will tend to hog CPU time as well as RAM, when it's not really needed.
Some resources to look at when it comes to this approach would be [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and its related classes, including the superclass, Service.  IntentService, however, it is worth noting handles a few more things about async Intent processing, etc that Service does not automatically come with.
Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's an interesting way to solve that. For my case, this solution would be a little bit over-engineered because in my example, it's all about "user convenience".

Comment: I suppose that's fair-- in my case, I also needed to have listeners running at all times, even when Activities weren't open, for certain intents.  That said, the other thing I was trying to remember is actually what hovanessyan mentions about `SharedPreferences`.  I have also used `SharedPreferences` with good success for this kind of problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      {
    public void onClick(View view)         {
        String name=username.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("username", name);
        if(name.equals("xxx"))                 {
            Intent intent=new Intent(currentactivity.this,nextactivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
        }
    }
});
```